# Empty form action no longer go to self after upgrade to Coldfusion 10 from 9

Tags: forms, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I often used empty values in my form action attributes to submit the form back to itself. This has worked for me for years using both CF7 and CF9. Recently, I updated to CF10 Update 14 and both my local development environment and our production servers now go to the site root instead of the current template when a form with an empty action string is submitted. Both environments are using IIS 7.5. Is there a configuration that can change this behavior, or are we no longer able to pass an empty string as a form action to submit a form to the same template?

Comment: ColdFusion has nothing to do with the way markup is executed and how requests are made from the client PC to the web server. The client side of things won't have changed, so presume when you upgraded CF, you also rejigged your IIS websites some how? I'm not familiar enough with IIS to comment on that side of things though.

Comment: I did have problems with the web connector properly setting up the handler mappings and ended up having to do them manually. It makes sense that this is an IIS issue, but it seems to be the CF install or updates that cause the configuration issue.

Comment: report to https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Comment: Curious, do you use `<CFFORM>`?

Comment: In this code, yes, it is using <cfform>.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a config change, but you could do `action="#cgi.script_name#?#cgi.query_string#"` to make it work the same.

Comment: But he shouldn't have to.

Comment: I agree with Raymond, but also agree with @Dan, I'm hoping to understand why upgrading or patching CF would modify the behavior of IIS.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't trying to excuse the 'break' here - just offering a work around.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with custom CGI params created by tomcat being different from those created by Jrun. What do you guys think?

Comment: @Mark, that seems to be very logical.

Answer (score 2):

If CF is at fault, it's because of `<CFFORM>`

I don't think there's anything you can do to fix this, but here's an explanation, and if you do submit a bug to CF, here's a good summary of the evidence, I think.

Testing this code in all tests:

```
<cfform action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted_" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="blank action" />
</cfform>

<Br><Br><br><br>

<cfform method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="no action" />
</cfform>

<Br><Br><br><br>

<cfform method="post" action="foo.cfm">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="foo.cfm action" />
</cfform>

<cfoutput>CF Version: #Server.ColdFusion.ProductVersion#</cfoutput>
```

CFLive uses CF 9.0.2, blank/no action results in the same.

```
<form name="CFForm_1" id="CFForm_1" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checkCFForm_1(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted_" value="true" />
<input type="submit" value="blank action" />
</form>
<Br><Br><br><br>
<form name="CFForm_2" id="CFForm_2" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checkCFForm_2(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<input type="submit" value="no action" />
</form>
<Br><Br><br><br>
<form name="CFForm_3" id="CFForm_3" action="foo.cfm" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checkCFForm_3(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<input type="submit" value="foo.cfm action" />
</form>
```

TryCF.com uses CF10.0.12 and inserts a value in blank/no action. `&#x2f;` = /

```
<form name="CFForm_1" id="CFForm_1" action="&#x2f;getremote.cfm" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checkCFForm_1(this)">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted_" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="blank action" />
</form>
<Br><Br><br><br>
<form name="CFForm_2" id="CFForm_2" action="&#x2f;getremote.cfm" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checkCFForm_2(this)">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="no action" />
</form>
<Br><Br><br><br>
<form name="CFForm_3" id="CFForm_3" action="foo.cfm" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checkCFForm_3(this)">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="foo.cfm action" />
</form>
```

CF Version: 10.0.12,286680

Of course, it's tough to say from this end if it's the guys at TryCF running some security-control on certain tags, however, foo.cfm is not interfered with and a plain `<form>` tag is not interfered with so it's probably not a case of handling a security concern.

---

I don't presently have access to an ACF server, so can't test myself.

---

And for the record, here is railo's output of the above code. Being mostly-compatible with CF 10, Railo generically identifies itself as CF ten for cross-compatibility version checks.

Railo, however, will leave a blank action blank, but it will not leave out an action attribute if one is not specified.

I did omit the javascript from all output samples, not relevant here, and already monotonous enough to read :).

```
<form onsubmit="return railo_form_47.check();" name="CFForm_47" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted_" value="true" />
<input type="submit" value="blank action" />
</form>
<Br><Br><br><br>
<form onsubmit="return railo_form_48.check();" name="CFForm_48" action="/railo/CAE86C59-B0B7-4FD6-894B1F178CEB6404.cfm?showdebugoutput=false" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<input type="submit" value="no action" />
</form>
<Br><Br><br><br>
<form onsubmit="return railo_form_49.check();" name="CFForm_49" action="foo.cfm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<input type="submit" value="foo.cfm action" />
</form>
CF Version: 10,0,0,0
```

---

For anyone else who may have this problem, a program like Notepad++ with complex regex capabilities, and **backing up before hand**, this regex can assist you.

Find all `<cfform>` with no action attribute or blank

```
<cfform((?![^>]*action\s*=\s*("[^"]+"|'[^']+')))([^>]*)>
```

And finally, this should do to strip empty actions and repopulate with actions like Raymond suggests.

```
Find: <cfform([^>]*)(?:\s*action\s*=\s*(?:""|'')\s*)([^>]*)*>
Replace: \<cfform action="\#cgi\.script\_name\#?\#cgi\.query\_string\#" \1 \2\>
```

Answer (score 0):

One item that is also in play is that these forms are included files using the mura tag within Mura CMS.

After several tests, I see that when I use standard form tags and include the method attribute it works correctly.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "foo") and form.foo neq "">
    <cfdump var="#form#">
<cfelse>
    <form action="" name="test" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="foo">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
</cfif>
```

If I remove the method="post" attribute, I return to the form and the dump is not shown.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "foo") and form.foo neq "">
    <cfdump var="#form#">
<cfelse>
    <form action="" name="test">
        <input type="text" name="foo">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</cfif>
```

If I change the above code to us cfform tags, the action is being modified to be /index.cfm. I feel that this might be due to rewrite rules that are in place, but I'm not sure why switching to cfform would have that effect.

Adding the method="post" attribute with the cfform tags produce the same results.

Outside of Mura I have found the following:

Using native form tags with the method="post" attribute works as expected.

Removing the method="post" attribute reloads the form and does not display the dump, the same behavior as when being included as a display_object in Mura.

Switching to cfform tags works properly with the method="post" attribute. Removing method="post" also works as cfform adds it back in on its own as the default if it is not included.

Ultimately, this behavior changed between CF9 and CF10.

Comment: If you have no reason to be using `<cfform>`, like reliance on cf form elements, you should move away from it. It often creates more problems than it's worth. (Even if you do rely on cf form elements, moving away from cf form elements should be a goal).